# Background service with repeat time

Tags: android, service

Hello i want to create a background service that will repeat at specific time each day to update the data from server, and until now i have this code:

```
public class Service_class extends Service {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

}
```

and i start the service with this code in main

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service_class.class));
```

How can i make this service repeat at exact time each day and never stop even if the app is closed? Thank you

Comment: you can use alarm manager for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AlaramManager` like below

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 10), pi);
```

// Millisec * Second

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AlarmManager** class for this

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, Service_class.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 60*60*24;//number of seconds
    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same requirement.i followed the below procedure.
In your service's `onCreate()`

```html
Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(this,AlarmHandle.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval = 86400*1000; // for getting called every 24 hours 
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Here the `AlarmHandle` class extends `BroadcastReceiver`. The `onReceive` of this receiver will get called during the time interval value mentioned.

Make sure the `AlarmHandle` is mentioned with receiver tag in the AndroidManifest file.

```html
<receiver android:name=".AlarmHandle">
</receiver>
```

Comment: what i have to put on receive method of the AlarmHandle?

Comment: onReceive is the function will get called every "interval" time period. What to put in that method is upto you. You mentioned in the question that, you want "to update the data from server". so you can handle that code here.

Comment: so the service i have to start it each time the app is open?

Comment: The alarm manager you are starting in the onCreate of the Service. yes? (i have shown it in the code). So during the time out the alarm manager will call the AlarmHandle (as per the above code) . once its started, you dont have to start it. (Dont keep the alarm start in the onCreate of your App main activity, make a service class and then call it in that. Why will start your service again and again?